# JSON in MySQL where condition

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I have the following JSON List: `'["Foo","Bar"]'`
The following entries are in my MySQL table t

```
Name   | Color
--------------
Foo    | Red
Bar    | Blue
Foobar | Green
```

Is there a way to use my JSON List as a condition in my where clause and get the same result like:

```
select * from t where name in ('Foo','Bar')
```

?

Comment: `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS( @json_list, CONCAT('"', Name, '"')`

Comment: It can be this simple.  Thanks alot! But note that you are missing a closing paranthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Akina solved it:
SELECT * FROM t WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(  '["Foo","Bar"]', CONCAT('"', Name, '"') )

Comment: I think you should convert the comment to an answer @Akina

Answer (score -1):

From my knowledge you can put multiple WHERE statements on a SQL query

See: https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_where.asp
you just need to add a 'AND' or 'OR' after each condition

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Mexico' 
    AND Address='Avda. de la Constitución 2222' 
    OR Address='Mataderos 2312';
;
```

So you just build the string you need before using
with c# you can do something like (just AND operators):

```
public List<Data> ExecuteQueryAND(List<string> statements, string table)
{
   // initial connection
   // ...

   string str = $"SELECT * FROM {table}\n";
   for (int i =0; i > statements.Count; i++) 
   {
      if( i == 0 ) 
      {
         str = str + $"WHERE {statements[i]}\n";
      }
      str = str + $"\tAND {statements[i]}\n";
   }
   str = str + ";";

   Console.WriteLine("Sql Query: " + str);
   // more code to execute sql
}
```

then when you call it:

```
// some code ..
   FilterList = ExecuteQueryAND( new List<string> { "Access=\"ADMIN\""});
// more code ..
```

Comment: you can test the example query here https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where

Comment: I hope it helped, let me now if you have more questions

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your nswer. As far as I see, you don't use that JSON list after all

Comment: The Json List would enter in the List thing on the entry for the function